# Comparing Two SharePoint Lists SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell, if-statement, sharepoint, foreach

I am writing some PowerShell and looking to compare two lists. I have List1 and List2. List1 and List2 both have a **Code** column I am looking to compare. List1 has a **Status** column and I would only like to compare the two if that column is equal to "Approved". All List1 Codes should be  in List2 if Approved

```
$Name1= "List1"
$Name2= "List2"

$List1= Get-PnPList -Connection $Connection -Web $Web -Identity $Name1
$List2= Get-PnPList -Connection $Connection -Web $Web -Identity $Name2

$List1Items= Get-PnPListItem -Connection $Connection -Web $Web -List $List1-Fields "Code", "Overall_x0020_Status"
$List2Items= Get-PnPListItem -Connection $Connection -Web $Web -List $List2-Fields "Code"

foreach ($item in $List1Items) {

    if ($item.FieldValues.Overall_x0020_Status -eq "Approved" -and $item.FieldValues.Code -eq $List2Items.FieldValues.Code)
    {
        Write-Host $List2Items.FieldValues.Code
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the desired output is all codes from List2 that are marked as Approved in List1?

Here's my take on it, with minimal modification to your existing script, and with zero optimization:

```
$Name1= "List1"
$Name2= "List2"

$List1= Get-PnPList -Connection $Connection -Web $Web -Identity $Name1
$List2= Get-PnPList -Connection $Connection -Web $Web -Identity $Name2

$List1Items= Get-PnPListItem -Connection $Connection -Web $Web -List $List1 -Fields "Code", "Overall_x0020_Status"
$List2Items= Get-PnPListItem -Connection $Connection -Web $Web -List $List2 -Fields "Code"

foreach ($item1 in $List1Items) {
    if ($item1.FieldValues.Overall_x0020_Status -eq "Approved") {
        foreach ($item2 in $List2Items) {
            if ($item1.FieldValues.Code -eq $item2.FieldValues.Code) {
                 Write-Host $item2.FieldValues.Code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output should be codes from List2 that were Approved in List1.

Note that the above code is very inefficient, and would iterate over List2 for every item in List1.  Here's a more optimized version:

```
$Name1= "List1"
$Name2= "List2"

$List1= Get-PnPList -Connection $Connection -Web $Web -Identity $Name1
$List2= Get-PnPList -Connection $Connection -Web $Web -Identity $Name2

$List1Items= Get-PnPListItem -Connection $Connection -Web $Web -List $List1 -Fields "Code", "Overall_x0020_Status"
$List2Items= Get-PnPListItem -Connection $Connection -Web $Web -List $List2 -Fields "Code"

$approved = @{} # hashtable of approved codes

# find approved codes in List1
foreach ($item in $List1Items) {
    if ($item.FieldValues.Overall_x0020_Status -eq "Approved") {
        $approved[$item.FieldValues.Code] = $true
    }
}

# find codes in List2 that are marked Approved in List1
foreach ($item in $List2Items) {
    if ($approved.ContainsKey($item.FieldValues.Code)) {
         Write-Host $item.FieldValues.Code
    }
}
```